# Spring Boot encoding / special characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, character-encoding

I have issue with encoding of Spring boot REST API special **cs_CS** characters.

Example:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public String test(){
    String specialCH = "ěščřžýáíéúů";
    System.out.println(specialCH);

    return specialCH;
}


2020-11-16 11:22:04.557  INFO 7400 --- [           main] cz.fry.chmi.ChmiApplication              : Started ChmiApplication in 5.187 seconds (JVM running for 5.703)
2020-11-16 11:22:05.167  INFO 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-16 11:22:05.168  INFO 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-11-16 11:22:05.175  INFO 7400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
ěščřžýáíéúů
```

**Result in browser:**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVjOK.png)

application.properties:

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

OS Windows 10 1909.

PS:
If I create file test.html ->

```
+ěššččřřžýáíéáý
```

**Result in browser:**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTqc.png)

Comment: Your `String specialCH = "ěščřžýáíéúů";` seems to be encoded as `cp852` but interpreted as `cp850` or `cp437`?

Comment: I don't know but if I set `server.servlet.encoding.charset=CP852` same result.

Comment: No, no, no! We are in 3rd millennium so switch to UTF-8 everywhere…

Comment: Yes, but every encoding `cp852 ISO8859-1/2 UTF-8` return `????` instead of `ěščř`

Comment: I mean another [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) mechanism. Here's an example in Python: `'ěščřžýáíé'.encode('cp850','replace').decode('cp850')` yields `?????ýáíé`. Sorry, I don't speak `java`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found solution**

Just need force UTF-8 encoding in Spring MVC returning String:

In `@RequestMapping`, use:

`produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + "; charset=utf-8"`